# How does the function work, that writes a command to the arduino LCD1602?

Tags: c++, c, function, arduino, bit-shift

I'm studying the Arduino and the LCD1602 display that comes with it without I2C. I have a sample code that displays information on this display, and I can't figure out how it does it.
In the LcdCommandWrite function, information is transmitted to the pins.

the function looks like this

```
void LcdCommandWrite(int value) {
// define all pins
int i = 0;
for (i=DB[0]; i <= DI; i++) // assign value for bus
{
digitalWrite(i,value & 01);
value >>= 1;
}
digitalWrite(Enable,LOW);
delayMicroseconds(1);
digitalWrite(Enable,HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(1); // wait for 1ms
digitalWrite(Enable,LOW);
delayMicroseconds(1); // wait for 1ms
}
```

the function call looks like this:
`LcdCommandWrite(0x38); // select as 8-bit interface, 2-line display, 5x7 character size`

- could you please explain especially the lines in the loop?:
  digitalWrite(i,value & 01);
  value >>= 1;
- is it necessary to turn on and off the LCD like this?:

```
digitalWrite(Enable,LOW);
delayMicroseconds(1);
digitalWrite(Enable,HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(1); // wait for 1ms
digitalWrite(Enable,LOW);
delayMicroseconds(1); // wait for 1ms
```

- it always seemed to me that only HIGH and LOW are transmitted to digital pins.
  why there`s something like (value & 01)? is it a binary code?

in my understanding, some binary code or command is transmitted to the pins of the LCD display, where they are subsequently executed.
are there any specific commands/sequences that display something on the screen, or switch pixels?

full code look like this:

```
int DI = 12;
int RW = 11;
int DB[] = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};// use array to select pin for bus
int Enable = 2;
void LcdCommandWrite(int value) {
// define all pins
int i = 0;
for (i=DB[0]; i <= DI; i++) // assign value for bus
{
digitalWrite(i,value & 01);// for 1602 LCD, it uses D7-D0( not D0-D7) for signal identification; here, it‘s used for signal inversion.
value >>= 1;
}
digitalWrite(Enable,LOW);
delayMicroseconds(1);
digitalWrite(Enable,HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(1); // wait for 1ms
digitalWrite(Enable,LOW);
delayMicroseconds(1); // wait for 1ms
}
void LcdDataWrite(int value) {
// initialize all pins
int i = 0;
digitalWrite(DI, HIGH);
digitalWrite(RW, LOW);
for (i=DB[0]; i <= DB[7]; i++) {
digitalWrite(i,value & 01);
value >>= 1;
}
digitalWrite(Enable,LOW);
delayMicroseconds(1);
digitalWrite(Enable,HIGH);
delayMicroseconds(1);
digitalWrite(Enable,LOW);
delayMicroseconds(1); // wait for 1ms
}
void setup (void) {
int i = 0;
for (i=Enable; i <= DI; i++) {
pinMode(i,OUTPUT);
}
delay(100);
// initialize LCD after a brief pause
// for LCD control
LcdCommandWrite(0x38); // select as 8-bit interface, 2-line display, 5x7 character size
delay(64);
LcdCommandWrite(0x38); // select as 8-bit interface, 2-line display, 5x7 character size
delay(50);
LcdCommandWrite(0x38); // select as 8-bit interface, 2-line display, 5x7 character size
delay(20);
LcdCommandWrite(0x06); // set input mode
// auto-increment, no display of shifting
delay(20);
LcdCommandWrite(0x0E); // display setup
// turn on the monitor, cursor on, no flickering
delay(20);
LcdCommandWrite(0x01); // clear the scree, cursor position returns to 0
delay(100);
LcdCommandWrite(0x80); // display setup
// turn on the monitor, cursor on, no flickering
delay(20);
}
void loop (void) {
LcdCommandWrite(0x01); // clear the scree, cursor position returns to 0
delay(10);
LcdCommandWrite(0x80+3);
delay(10);
// write in welcome message
LcdDataWrite('W');
LcdDataWrite('e');
LcdDataWrite('l');
LcdDataWrite('c');
LcdDataWrite('o');
LcdDataWrite('m');
LcdDataWrite('e');
LcdDataWrite(' ');
LcdDataWrite('t');
LcdDataWrite('o');
delay(10);
LcdCommandWrite(0xc0+1); // set cursor position at second line, second position
delay(10);
LcdDataWrite('g');
LcdDataWrite('e');
LcdDataWrite('e');
LcdDataWrite('k');
LcdDataWrite('-');
LcdDataWrite('w');
LcdDataWrite('o');
LcdDataWrite('r');
LcdDataWrite('k');
LcdDataWrite('s');
LcdDataWrite('h');
LcdDataWrite('o');
LcdDataWrite('p');
delay(5000);
LcdCommandWrite(0x01); // clear the screen, cursor returns to 0
delay(10);
LcdDataWrite('i');
LcdDataWrite(' ');
LcdDataWrite('a');
LcdDataWrite('m');
LcdDataWrite(' ');
LcdDataWrite('n');
LcdDataWrite('i');
LcdDataWrite('k');
LcdDataWrite('i');
LcdDataWrite('t');
LcdDataWrite('a');
delay(3000);
LcdCommandWrite(0x02); // set mode as new characters replay old ones, where there is no new ones remain the same
delay(10);
LcdCommandWrite(0x80+5); // set cursor position at first line, sixth position
delay(10);
LcdDataWrite('t');
LcdDataWrite('h');
LcdDataWrite('e');
LcdDataWrite(' ');
LcdDataWrite('a');
LcdDataWrite('d');
LcdDataWrite('m');
LcdDataWrite('i');
LcdDataWrite('n');
delay(5000);
}
```

What the arduino circuit with an LCD display looks like is attached in the photo
[image]

I tried to search the Internet for what exactly is being fed to the input to the function, I got ASCII character encoding, but I don't understand exactly how these characters are transmitted to the LCD display

I also roughly understood how bitwise shift works, but did not understand what role it performs in these functions.

Comment: First you must see the LCD1602 datasheet. From this documentation, you can understand about pins name and procedure to display character on LCD. The code just follow this procedure. It is just promise between LCD 1602 and your processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should go through the datasheet of the LCD. I just googled and randomly came across a few.

1. https://www.openhacks.com/uploadsproductos/eone-1602a1.pdf
2. https://www.waveshare.com/datasheet/LCD_en_PDF/LCD1602.pdf
3. https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/TC1602A-01T.pdf

**Note*** Use the part number of the LCD you have to get the appropriate/specific datasheet.

Short description:
It's an 8-bit parallel line LCD. Therefore, the data/ command are being sent parallelly by making respected bit pins high and low `digitalWrite(i, value & 01);`. `value >>= 1` and `(value & 01)` is nothing but a left-shift and logical `AND` to check/ read values of each bit (later on, set the respective bit). You must also read about bitwise operations.
https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/bitwise-operators

In the following command, `LcdCommandWrite(0x38)`, `0x38` is an 8-bit data that will be sent on 8 data pins. So it could be like `D7=0,D6=0,D5=1,D4=1,D3=1,D2=0,D1=0,D0=0` (0x38 hex= 00111000 binary).

So compare the datasheet with the code, and you will understand everything.

**Note*** Other than Data/ command pins, there are some control pins to tell the LCD controllers to manage data flow and command operations.